# C++ deduce member function parameters

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I'm looking to extend the functionality described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22632236/how-is-possible-to-deduce-function-argument-type-in-c) but for member functions, what would be the syntax in this case?

Also, the (*) in the template definition, is that de-referencing the function pointer so the compiler can deduce the template arguments?

Would appreciate any input!

Thanks

```
template <class F> struct ArgType;

template <class R, class T> 
struct ArgType<R(*)(T)> {
  typedef T type;
}; 

void f(int) {}

#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

  // To prove
  std::cout << std::is_same< ArgType<decltype(&f)>::type, int >::value << '\n';

  // To use
  ArgType<decltype(&f)>::type a;
}
```

Comment: The `*` in the template definition is simply part of the syntax for a function pointer.

Comment: This is a function pointer, and you need a member function pointer, which is a `R(T::*)(Args...)`

Comment: Decomposing a member function type is usually done in something called a "member function (type) trait". There are several implementations already on StackOverflow; boost also contains one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pointer-to-members look like `Ret (Cls::*)(Args...) [cv-qualifiers] [ref-qualifiers]`. So you can extend your class to deduce the first type thusly:

```
template <class F> struct ArgType;

template <typename Ret, typename Cls, typename T, typename... Args>
struct ArgType<Ret (Cls::*)(T, Args...)> {
    using type = T;
};
```

Note that you can make this more generic by write a metafunction that gives you the `n`th argument:

```
template <typename Ret, typename Cls, typename... Args>
struct ArgType<Ret (Cls::*)(Args...)> {
    
    template <size_t N>
    struct get_arg {
        using type = typename std::tuple_element<N,
                        std::tuple<Args...>>::type;
    };
};
```

So `ArgType<F>::arg<0>::type` would be the type you seek.

Comment: Plus assorted cv-qualifier/ref-qualifier/C varargs variations; you'd need 24 partial specializations...

Comment: @T.C. Omitted for sanity.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! Very helpful, always find the pointer to member function syntax a bit of a tongue twister + with templates thrown in there my tiny brain cannot cope.

Cheers!

Comment: Has anyone actually tried this? It doesn't work for me ("expected a type, got ‘&Bar::doSomething’")

Comment: @JeffTrull Right, you need to pass a type... `decltype(&Bar::doSomething)`.

Comment: That was it! Thank you.